# Permutation, Even algo and reverse elimination

Tags: optimization, permutation, reverse

I coded a function that implement Even's alogrithm to find all permuations of a increasing sorted vector. But I don't need the "reverse" route, i.e the route that is the same when you read it starting at the end. So far, I "rewind" and compare all my permutation and eliminate the "reverse" route but it takes me half of my runing time to reverse, so is there a way to adapt the algorithm to get only half the permutation but with no reverse one ?

Comment: Ok, I've found a way to eliminate 'reverse' doublon, I reverse line by line half of the matrix containing the permutation and apply some functions to delete commune line btw old matrix and new, but I check on basic example , it is working but I wonder if it is on much larger one ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found the solution, Indeed , if you have, as I had, a sorted list of consecutive number, when your originally first number becomes the last and last becomes the first, you start to create 'reverse' permutation, i.e you obtain the same list as you have before bif you read in reverse way.

So, the condition, if originally first is last AND originally last is first, break, is efficient and time sparing.